# NUL (^@) at shutdown/restart

Tags: realtek, dkms

> OS:20.10

I installed a Realtek 8821 PCle Wi-Fi driver using DKMS source (rtl8821ce-dkms) and when I shutdown or restart my computer, it showed the following 
`^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`

> Update: it also froze the shutdown.

I switched back to "Do not use the device" then it becomes normal again.
And if I don't use a driver Ubuntu will be frozen when I connect to Wi-Fi.

Comment: You haven't provided your OS & particularly release details; you may (*if using a LTS release*) have two kernel stack choices & a fix maybe switching to the other kernel stack choice.

Comment: Check your version and report carefully. 20.10 is currently obsolete. `lsb_release -a` will show you